# Finding following html element in Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find following element

```
<button type="button" class="btn filters-button"><i class="icon-filter"></i> Filters</button>
```

using below code:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.filters-button").click()
```

I get a message that it is `unable to locate element`, do you know what may be an issue here?

Thank you for your help in advance

Tried using XPATH with no result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the limited information provided in the question, below are the trouble shooting you can try:

1. **Try the below code instead using Selenium's** [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/):

```
# using XPATH locator strategy
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()=' Filters']"))).click()

# using CSS Selector locator strategy
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.filters-button"))).click()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

2. **Check for presence of IFRAME**: If the desired element is within an IFRAME, then you need to switch into the IFRAME first to perform click action.

Refer below answer to switch info the IFRAME:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75813942/7598774

Comment: It was the iframe, after switching everything works fine, thanks :)