# Selenium find element by link_text or Xpath - ElementNotFoundException

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have an href on the website which which looks like this:

```
<a href="Redirect.jsp?ScreenCode=L0000" target="LinkFrame">Transfer Doc</a>
```

This element is even visible  when i expect the browser window opened by Selenium.

**Problem:**

I am trying to find this element and tried the following approaches:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
... #navigation to current site
transDocBtn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href,"L0000")]')
transDocBtn = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"Transfer Doc")
```

Neither of the 2 lines find the element. Both return an ElementNotFoundException.

How can i find my link? What is the reason the both lines above do not work?

**Edit:**
For Reference, this is what the structure roughly looks like. My Element is within the `body class=menu`

[image]

Comment: can you share url? or check if website have some iframe

Comment: The website is locked under a login. However there might be an iframe (i dont know exactly what that is sadly), as ive come across multiple <frame> elements when i printed out driver.page_source

Comment: Check this answer for IFRAME - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75813942/7598774

Comment: @Wonka however i just checked and there seems to be only a single frame. With driver.switch_to.frame() i can only switch to frame 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("Your URL")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//frame[@name='LinkFrame']")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(frame))

transDocBtn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href,"L0000")]')))

# Below code should be used to come out of FRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```